# Is possible to create a printing server with xamp?

Tags: php, printing, xampp

Is possible to make a printserver with xampp so i can conect a usb printer to a computer and print files on the same network using any device?
Is possible to print the file in a printer with  php?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just share the usb printer to the network? e.g. https://pureinfotech.com/share-usb-printer-network-windows-10/

Comment: I’m sure you could write a socket listener in PHP that can forward incoming print requests to the connected printer… but why? This is functionality most operating systems support by default. There should not be any need to write this yourself. Keep in mind that it’s not just about printing something, you would need to implement support for status communication as well (ink levels, supported paper sizes and color modes, and so on).

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean as a "printing server", if you could please elaborate more. Yes, it's possible using PHP [execution operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) and depending on whether using Linux or Windows, and the CLI-API of something like [CUPS](https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html) or [LPR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/lpr). There are also several libraries online that provide the functionality for implementation of the above and others.